# Unable to Select Text Across Elements within Shadow DOM

Tags: contenteditable, shadow-dom, custom-element

I'm currently utilizing Custom Elements within a  with the attribute contenteditable=true.

However, I've encountered an issue with the shadow DOM, as it seems to prevent me from selecting text across multiple elements.

I'm seeking insights into the underlying reasons for this behavior and any potential approaches to address it. Could anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

what you tried: I have no clue at all

what you expected to happen: select text across elements

what actually resulted: [Take a look at this example on CodePen](https://codepen.io/cqbyte/pen/rNodjOx)

```
<div class="content" contenteditable>
  <p>Why am I unable to use the mouse to select 'hello' and 'world'?</p>
  
  <c-text>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>world</p>
  </c-text>
</div>
```

```
const template = document.createElement('template');

template.innerHTML = `
    <style>
    div { border: 1px solid black; }
    </style>
    <div><slot></slot></div>
`;

window.customElements.define('c-text', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Known bug that crept into a recent 116.nnn update, Chromium team is working on it:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1484447

You can ductape (or WD40) it by setting any style property:

```html
<script>
customElements.define('c-text', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super().attachShadow({mode:'open'}).innerHTML = "<slot></slot>";
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    if (this.hasAttribute("nofix")) return;

    // alas these lines now have to go into all components using contenteditable
    // the connectedCallback fires on the opening tag
    // so settimeout required because innerHTML won't exist 
    // when DOM is created *after* the WC was created
    setTimeout( () => this.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable]")
                .forEach( el => el.style.display=null ));
    
  }
});
</script>

<c-text>
  <h1 contenteditable>I am fixed, edit me</h1>
</c-text>

<c-text nofix>
  <h1 contenteditable>I am not fixed, can't edit me</h1>
</c-text>
```